# Dynamic Braking MOSFET Control Circuit

Tags: voltage, pwm, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am dealing with a regenerative power situation with BLDC motor and servo drive controller.The power supply is 48V regulated DC but during deceleration due to regeneration, the voltage at drive increases beyond 48 V

[image]

I plan to dissipate the reverse current through power resistor in the form of heat. To achieve this dynamic braking, the driver circuit for MOSFET switch has to turn ON during regeneration when voltage exceeds certain limit and turn off when the voltage drops. I tried  looking for hysteretic comparator to generate signal for switch but could not find for such voltage level. Can you suggest any different technique for controlling the Braking MOSFET switch?

Answer (score 3):

The way you normally (or often) achieve what you want is by letting the braking current charge back into the power-supply raising the voltage on the supply, what you then do is you put an over-voltage-protection circuit on the supply which will bypass/sink current to ground if the voltage on the supply exceeds the intended voltage (in your case 48v). here is a very crude exsample of how this can be accomplished.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi53IH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This exsample is made using a half-bridge output, when the voltage at the output exceeds the supply voltage the diode across the top FET allows the power to run back into the supply, If the supply voltage increases to more than 48v the zener will start conducting and will dissapate the extra power in the zener and in the resistor in series. this is a very crude way to clamp the supply voltage to gnd in the case of an overvoltage and it can be done much better but this is just to give you an idea of how it is done.

Comment: This works well for small motors, not so much for big amp goliaths. But the OP did not mention power levels so tis still good to go.

Comment: Yes I agree, but as I sayed it was just a crude exsample of how it's done; The way we do at my work is that we measure the voltage on Vcc with a comparator and then we switch a low-value big-ass-power-resistor across the supply rail with a big-ass-fet when the voltage on the rail exceeds the indended supply voltage.

Comment: Yup, I used the above a lot for little servo motors and steppers. I suspect the OP's 48 motor may be rather larger though with lots of inertia, so had to mention it for completeness of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not regenerative braking. That would require an energy harvester to extract power from the motor and boost it up or down to feed it back into your battery or a capacitor bank.

It is not really dynamic braking either if you are not back-driving the motor, which you have not indicated you are.

However, to answer your question as written, to make a hysteresis comparator you simply need to add positive feedback around a regular comparator circuit. The circuit below is an example of that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faOMXm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage dividers on the left bring down the 48V and the motor voltage to a level that the comparator can handle. The left too set the threshold voltage. R5 provides the hysteresis that changes the threshold value depending on the state of the output of the comparator.

The two circuits below show you the effective resistor dividers in each state. As indicated the motor voltage would need to exceed ~52V before the load resistor plugs in and it will stay plugged in till the motor voltage falls below ~50V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Jiws.png)</sup>

---

**Unfortunately** that may not quite work as you expect it to. What will happen in reality is the circuit above will turn on which will in turn pull down the voltage coming from the motor causing the circuit to turn off again. Repeat... That is, it will oscillate. You can alleviate that somewhat by adding a large capacitor on the motor side of your blocking diode.

There are more linear circuits you could use.. but the MOSFET heat needs to be dealt with. As such these are generally better for lower power applications.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFcDbF.png)</sup>

Ultimately you might be better sequencing these parts using whatever micro you are using to drive this.

Comment: As you mentioned yourself the circuit you provided would oscillate, but it would probably work as intended if you just remove the schmitt trigger completely. What you have made then is just a circuit that regulated the voltage on the output, however because you are sinking through the fet it can only pull the output low when it is above the reference voltage, and not pull it high when it is below it. as is the intention..

Comment: ..The last circuit you provided is probably the way to go, neat little circuit by the way; props for that!

Comment: @Vinzent yup. The first circuit really needs a large storage cap to recover some of that motor energy. The circuit then just limits the charge on that and, if designed right, would self oscillate at some lower frequency that the MOSFET can handle. OP would need to play with all that to optimize it though. I considered making it linear, but the second circuit is so much simpler.

Comment: @Trevor : Yes of course the large capacitor on motor side will be needed. I forgot to mention in reference diagram as the schematic I posted was just to give clear idea what query I had. I'll  keep that in mind. I just want to add in the here I will be dealing with currents upto 25 A max from supply voltage under normal working operation depending on load and switching command given by servo drive controller

Comment: -1 as DClink chopper to manage regenerative energy is industry standard. Why would you overcomplicate matters with a linear alternative.  The use of a comparator to drive a switch to load the DClink with a resistor is more than adequate. Yes the frequency of the chopping with change based upon the energy being dump ie 0.5Jw^2 so at higher velocities it is higher freq. A power engineer & control engineer would design the velocity, current loop in conjunction of teh chopper such that the freq rarely goes above 1kHz

Comment: @JonRB  I simply implied without some bulk capacitance to limit that frequency there may be an issue. The linear method is simply an alternative. It is of course all dependent on the power and inertia of the motor too, which the OP never mentioned.

Comment: @JonRB Continued: Further, as I pointed out at the start of the answer, the OPs approach is neither a regenerative nor a dynamic braking solution. It is entirely in the wrong spot. I have to assume he is doing the braking switch-mode in whatever bridge follows this circuit. As described, this requirement is simply for over-voltage protection.

Comment: @Trevor: I never mentioned that I am implementing regenerative braking. But I would like to know why this approach is different dynamic braking. May be you can elaborate to clarify my thought.

Comment: @JonRB : I mentioned about Hysteretic comparator in my query. But I didn't have clear idea for implementing it for around 48V, thus I raised the query. May be you can provide any industrial solution to my query.

Comment: @AG47 1. You mention regeneration in the second sentence of your question text. 2. Dynamic braking is the use of the electric traction motors of a vehicle as generators when slowing. It is termed rheostatic if the generated electrical power is dissipated as heat in brake grid resistors, and regenerative if the power is returned to the supply line. Since your resistor only comes into play when the back emf > supply it's not dynamic braking, and you are not feeding the current back to the supply, so it is not regenerative.

Comment: @AG47 I believe what you are actually attempting is controlled (hopefully) motor power reversal to apply a braking torque.

Comment: @AG47 but then again, your schematic only shows the smallest snippet of your circuit, so perhaps I am missing something you are not showing me.

Comment: @Trevor: The circuit i mentioned is just a concept which i want to verify. In the second sentence itself i mentioned the word "deceleration" which means slowing down. Thus the energy either can be fed back to power supply or lost in the form of heat through a resistor.

Comment: @Trevor: Again in the second paragraph i mentioned about energy being dissipated through power resistor. I am not getting a clear idea why it differs from dynamic braking.

Comment: @AG47 yes but you also said regeneration. But anyhow, without showing what comes next in your circuit, and how you plan on driving it during deceleration, I can't really comment much further. If your bridge driver is flipping the motor so the back EMF is on top of the 48V rail and the circuit above is replicated per bridge arm, it might work but would not be the best way to do it, but I have no idea what you are actually doing/planning there.

Comment: @Trevor: May be I was not able to explain my question properly. I used the term regeneration to tell that the terminal voltage on the servo drive got increased and there is reverse current flow. Regenerative braking is out of picture. I have edited the circuit for your reference.

Comment: @AG47, that's fine. I'd love to see what the servo drive circuit is though.

Comment: @Trevor_G I am using a third party servo drive from Elmo MC's  Bassoon drive. They don't provide the circuit diagram. But you can get the block diagram from their documentation.

Answer (score -2):

What you've described is a [Schmitt Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger).

> In electronics, a Schmitt trigger is a comparator circuit with hysteresis implemented by applying positive feedback to the noninverting input of a comparator or differential amplifier.

Many different implementation methods are available.

Comment: I'm half asleep, or I'd write more. Feel free to flesh it out.