# Motor regeneration Circuit Issues

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I've been trying to get a motor regen power dissipation circuit working that I pulled from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348255/dynamic-braking-mosfet-control-circuit/348268#348268).  The circuit works as provided but when I attempt to modify the load resistor, the mosfet is not longer being switched at 10-12V, it generally falls down to 5V or so.  It appears that the BJT isn't being driven fully and thus the mosfet is not being driven fully.  I'm at a loss as to why this is the case, can anyone explain this?

[Attached are the LTSpice simulation files.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/907n9szr52xane8/motor_clamp.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the emitter and base of Q1 around (including base resistor), so that the Vrop across D1 is enough to enable Q2. Q1 MUST have a base voltage at least .65 volts lower than the emitter for it to work and drive the MOSFET.

The following circuit will dump current based on a voltage higher than D4 + 4 volts. At a lower voltage it has no effect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3hKep.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks for getting back to me!  I was unclear as to what I meant by load, which in this case would be R1.  The circuit I want will dump energy provided by Vout (a motor being backdriven) through R1 when Vout exceeds a particular threshold above Vin.  If I'm right in understanding this circuit, it will dump load when Vout is less than Vin and not the other way around, correct?

Comment: Then you need to use MOV's or Sidacs to clamp the over voltage. If you know what the exact 'over voltage' point is then a zener diode can be used to turn ON M1.

Comment: D4 would be equal to the expected minimum back-EMF voltage minus 2.5 volts.

Comment: That's pretty much perfect.  I liked the idea (at least what I understood to be the idea) from the original circuit by @Trevor_G in the other post in that it would always trigger based on a differential voltage and thus work for any supply voltage.  But, this circuit is very stable, showing no oscillation compared to the original or to a similar comparator based circuit.  I like it.

Comment: I suppose the only problem might be transistor heating when in the linear region.  Either bigger mostfet or a schmidt trigger should deal with that though.

Comment: Actually, the Mosfet pretty much always sits in the linear region with this circuit, that's probably not going to work well.

Comment: I am on my cellphone. Mosfet needs to be on a large heatsink.