# BLDC Driver "Input High Voltage" Fault

Tags: resistors, brushless-dc-motor, braking

In the system I designed, there are 2 motor drivers and 2 motors. Motor drivers are powered by 48V. The rated power of my motor is 400W. I drive the motor at 1500 RPM.

When there is a sudden load change in the motor, the supply of the motor drivers goes over 50 Volts and shuts itself off with a high voltage error. When I drive the motor with 750 RPM, there is no problem. I think the problem is related to regenerative energy.

I connected 12 pieces of 63V 4700uF parallel capacitors between the power supply and the drivers to absorb the regenerative energy. I don't get the "input high voltage" warning up to 1000 RPM, I guess it worked. Some people also suggest connecting a resistor in parallel with this capacitor structure. How can I calculate this resistor value?

How can I solve this problem? Will using a resistor fix the problem? Can you help me?

---

Motor Spec:

[image]

Motor Brake Spec:

[image]

Power Supply Spec:

[image]

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: If the equipment were battery powered, you could add circuitry to dump the excess into the battery : or re-engineer the motor control to do that for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by dump the excess into the battery. I'm using a power supply to feed the motor drivers.

Comment: The question didn't say what the source of power was. As my comment said, it only applies in battery powered equipment. You don't have that option.

Comment: My fault, sorry.

Comment: @EnesOrhan - Welcome :-) Part of the "Stack Exchange approach" is that questions and answers are in separate places - different from typical internet forums. If you want to add new information to your question, you must click [Edit] below the question, *not* write the new information in the box below labeled "Your Answer" because *that isn't an answer*. Therefore I have deleted your "non-answer" and moved the new information into the question, as an edit. Please read the [tour] and [help] to see more site rules. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are only to improve questions or answers. Answers are solutions expected with certainty or methods to discover solutions.

Comment: I'm slowly getting used to it. Thanks for your correction :)

Answer (score 2):

For sure placing the resistor that is always connected across the capacitor bank is the worst idea you could get. The resistor will always draw a considerable power and it will heat.

- Build a chopper instead. A comparator with hysteresis that drives a gate driver and a low side MOSFET switch that turns ON/OFF the resistor, when voltage rises and then drops.
- Use a ramp function on speed setpoint, this will reduce the generated voltage.
- Use lower voltage rated motor. 48V driver would best fit for a motor nominal voltage of 24V.

Comment: I don't have a chance to change motors.
Can you send me the circuit diagram of the chopper circuit? I couldn't quite understand what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

It is common when driving motors, to use a "brake resistor" to limit regenerative current/voltage.  This is just a low value (maybe 5-10Ω for 48V/400W), high-wattage resistor which gets switched directly across the motor/bus when the voltage exceeds some threshold. This has the effect of absorbing the regenerative energy and keeping the bus voltage from rising too far. It is then switched off, to avoid overheating. The wattage is sized according to the maximum inertia / quantity of regenerative energy needing quenched.

Comment: I understand the braking resistor. but I don't know how to turn the resistor on and off. Do i have to do it with transistor? So should i check the trigger tip? Can you share the circuit diagram about this topic?

Comment: You will have to create a circuit to do this. A transistor could work, but a MOSFET would probably be easier. Detect when the bus voltage is above some point (say, 47V), and turn on the MOSFET (and under 47V turn it off.)  An op-amp with appropriate sense resistors could do this. Try searching here; I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348255/dynamic-braking-mosfet-control-circuit) - look at Trevor's answer.

Answer (score 0):

All this means is your power supply is unable to drive the current needed to suddenly absorb the excess power generated from a rising RPM due to a drop in load with back EMF acting as a generator.

When duty cycle is high and RPM is lower than no-load and RPM suddenly rises with drop in load, then no-load average voltage may be higher than driver average voltage.  in this case as @Marco suggests , you need a voltage error amplifier to lower the PWM duty cycle thus loading the back EMF which causes the over-voltage.

Dynamic compensation must be determined according the duration of the disturbance.

Alternatively lower the impedance of your 48V supply so that it has an ESR of 1% of the Motor DCR so that this “load regulation error” of 4% does not occur.  (Easier said than done without specs)

**rev A**

- Controlling rate of change of load must not exceed ability to match rate of change and amount of current.
- Achieving this low load regulation error is a matter of impedance ratios from source to load and rates of change controllability.
- to solve this , first you must define all these variables with details;  a spec,  schematic and photos
- source power, impedance, load inertial energy stored, power transfer, max V , t rise max.

**Rev B , new specs**

- Load Regulation error 0.5% of 48V = 240mV (good).  And 0.5% of 48V/42A= ~ 5.7 mOhms for “push” not necessarily “pull”.
- Inductive flyback (high from motor dI/dt).
- Load Caps on supply 4.7mF x6 unknown ESR … worst case net for 2V rise/12A drop =  1/6 Ohm or ESR*C= 4.7 ms but rise time of the current pulse determines frequency BW and impedance of pulse.  ESR= D.F.* |Xc| where |Xc|= T(rise time)/ 2pi 0.35 C)
- How this affects stability of supply is also important with power on surge currents and phase margin.
- network impedance of the load is complex ,so include wiring type, length and Cap datasheet link [**e.g.**](https://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/380-382.pdf) and if possible rise time of pulse with coax and AC coupled 50 load to DSO.
- finally Meanwell OVP is **programmable** to 115 % = 55V

  - This ought to be selected and use caps with higher than 63V for better quality and lower ESR.

Motor L = 0.55 mH. DCR = 0.25 Ohms.
Thus T=L/DCR= 220 ms +/-30%.
I load = 12A rated thus I *DCR = 4V so flyback voltage can be attenuated to 1V or 25% of this with cap ESR of 1/5 of 0.25 ohms or 50 mOhms with a C value C=T/DCR = 220 ms/50 mOhms = 4.4 Farads !  This can only be accomplished with SuperCaps or double electric layer caps or a battery.

**This suggests your best solution is a 48V battery with low ESR and a 12A battery charger /regulator for float voltage of 48V using an ESC motor controller rated for >= 1Hp  Hmm**

Q at resonance is \$Q=R\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$. Which for motor with supply caps L = 0.55mH,DCR = 0.25 Ohm C= 4.7mF * 6 , ESR = ?,
Or \$\dfrac{1}{Q} = \dfrac{1}{Q_L}+\dfrac{1}{Q_C}\$

Anyone see anything wrong with my calculations OR wish to simplfy or correct?? Go ahead.

Comment: I reduced the output of the 48 volt power supply to 44 volts with the potentiometer. But this was not a solution for me. Are you also talking about the brake chopper circuit?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, but there are a lot of unknowns for me in this answer. I still don't understand what my solution is and how I should proceed.

Comment: 1) show link to cap specs, 2) increase OVP to 115%